# Update field based on selected attribute from dropdown list

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select

Is it possible to assign an attribute from a list (table) based on a chosen attribute (code) from a dropdown list field?

[image: Input attributes]

For the selected code, field "Sifra", update field "Opis" with something from the codelist table.

Comment: I think the [Value Map widget](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-and-value-maps) might be helpful :)

Comment: thanks but i already did it with the field "Sifra" now i want to make a relation to another field depending of selected attribute from the dropdown list.